# How do you export an Excel document to PDF after cell value input?

Tags: excel, vba

**References**:

OS: Windows 10 Enterprise

Excel Pro Plus 2016 - 32bit

FileType - xlsm

**Operation Details**:

Once the last cell input box prompt is completed, the document should automatically export active sheet to PDF without need to save the document. The exported PDF should have a document name given from the *title* label cell & *pub* label cell.

**Code**:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)


Dim rngC As Range
    Set rngC = Intersect(Target, Me.Range("Publication"))
    
Dim trig As Range
Dim title As String
Dim pub As String

   Set trig = Intersect(Target, Me.Range("OldDoc"))

    
    Select Case True
    

    Case Not rngC Is Nothing

Dim entryDate As String

         entryDate = Format$(Now, "ddmmmm,yyyy")

         On Error GoTo SafeExit
         Application.EnableEvents = False

Dim cellc As Range

         For Each cellc In rngC
             If Not IsEmpty(cellc) Then
                cellc.Offset(1).Value = entryDate
             End If
    Next


    
        Case Not trig Is Nothing
        
    title = Range("Title").Text
    pub = Range("Publication").Text
        
        ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
                                    IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
                                    OpenAfterPublish:=True, Filename:=title & "-" & pub
        
End Select

    

SafeExit:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    
    


End Sub
```

**Additional Notes**:

I have included my entire worksheet_change code to show how I have all the processes laid out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Cell with the last input value is defined as follows:

```
Dim trig As Range

Set trig = Intersect(Target, Me.Range("OldDoc")) 'This will be the variable to trigger the export syntax
```

For this process I use the Case statement for my code to identify which statement is true and then perform that function. So We start with `Select Case True`.

To make the case statement true for this process we compare it as a false negative so when an input is made it will activate the export process:

```
Case Not trig Is Nothing 'This is looking to see for changes in the variable, then will proceed to the process syntax in the statement
```

To remove the process of saving the document prior to formatting to PDF, the argument `OpenAfterPublish:=True` for `ExportAsFixedFormat`. This will automatically open your excel document in adobe Acrobat or preferred PDF software for continued editing.

The final should look like this (when using the case statement format):

```
Dim trig As Range
Dim title As String
Dim pub As String

   Set trig = Intersect(Target, Me.Range("OldDoc"))

    
    Select Case True
        Case Not trig Is Nothing
        
    title = Range("Title").Text
    pub = Range("Publication").Text
        
        ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
                                    IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
                                    OpenAfterPublish:=True, Filename:=title & "-" & pub
        
End Select
```

***Note***:

All cell ranges are specified cell labels, interchange with preferred cells as needed. And please provide feedback as I am still developing with vba and the correct vocabulary.

Comment: If there is a much cleaner way of producing the same effect, I would love to learn.